# Get data from a PowerBI using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

My government have a website with an embed a PowerBI report (https://www.gov.br/anvisa/pt-br/acessoainformacao/dadosabertos/informacoes-analiticas/monografias-de-agrotoxicos), there is a download button in this report named "Arquivo CSV".

I'm trying to get this data using Power Automate, but I can't find the element of this button to use the click action in Power Automate, I've tried the click action and the download buttom action, also tried with different browsers.

I don't have the original PBI file nor the DB behind it, it is possible to get this data using Power Automate?

Comment: The URL for the CSV is https://dados.anvisa.gov.br/dados/TA_MONOGRAFIA_AGROTOXICO.csv

Comment: Hello Sam! Thanks for this answer, can you share how did you get  to the link please?

Comment: In Edge (and maybe Chrome) you can go to Downloads and then right click and select Copy Download link.